# Having a view push to a form in Django

Tags: django, forms

I'm having a bit of trouble with what seems to be a simple idea.

I have a view called `register`.  I want that view to take the user to a registration form that I've created.

```
def register(request):
    form = register()
    data = {}
    data.update(csrf(request))
    data.update({ 'form' : form })
    return render_to_response("register.html", data)


class register(forms.Form):
    rsb_first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 25, required = True)
    rsb_last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 25, required = True)
    rsb_company_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 25)
    rsb_address1 = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, required = True)
    rsb_address2 = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
    rsb_city = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, required = True)
    rsb_zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length = 25, required = True)
    rsb_phone_number = USPhoneNumberField(label = "Phone", widget = USPhoneNumberMultiWidget(), required = True)
    rsb_email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
```

When I go to `/register/` I receive the following error:

```
register() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

What argument is it expecting?

EDIT1:

Thanks to eakron I was able to see what problem I was having - now I'm having another issue altogether.

So, I renamed my view `registerUser`, changed the `urls.py` file to reflect that, and changed my form to `RegisterForm`.

Now my view is simply:

```
def registerUser(request):
    form = RegisterForm()
    data = {}
    data.update(csrf(request))
    data.update({ 'form' : form })
    return render_to_response("register.html", data)
```

And I receive the following error:

```
Could not import rsb.views.registerUser. View does not exist in module rsb.views.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Which line is the error referring to?

Comment: Really couldn't say what's wrong now. Are you sure everything got reloaded properly? Maybe this should be a new question though?

Comment: It is a new question now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771815/view-does-not-exist-in-module-when-it-does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your naming has caused a clash. Python doesn't know if you mean register the class or register the function, and the function is "closest". Rename one (or start the name of the class with a capital letter, which is the norm anyway).

Eg change it to

```
class Register(forms.Form)
```

etc